# throttle consumer in producer/consumer threads

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

There is a single consumer and single producer thread.  The producer thread data acquisition is slow.  It queries a socket for data and the time it takes to produce data for the consumer is significantly longer than the time it takes for the consumer to process and send the data out.  The problem is I am updating a display so I want the updates to slow down so they appear continuous rather than update in bursts.

I am using a double buffer right now but the consumer is waiting too long for the buffers to be swapped because the producer is taking too long to produce data.  Perhaps if I slice up the data into smaller blocks and use a queue instead?  That way the producer would feed the consumer a little at a time?  Has anyone ever run into this problem?

Comment: Why is updating the display immediately an issue? Doesn't that make your application seem slower than it actually is?

Comment: Yes.  It improves the user experience.  Right now it updates really fast then stops because it needs to fetch more data.  I want to spread the time out so there are no stops.  Is there another simpler way I can achieve this?

Comment: Artificially throttling down a consumer thread kind of defies the use of threads, to be honest. The main reason why one uses threads is that things seem to go faster (and in the case of multiprocessing actually do go faster) because the consumer _does not block_ while the producer is reading. If you throttle down the consumer, you could as well scratch the entire multithreading and just write to the screen whatever comes over the wire as it comes.

Comment: There was a question not long ago about smoothing out download progress bars, but I'm too lazy to search for it.

Comment: If I write to the screen as it comes then it abruptly stops when it runs out of data.  I need to spread the time out for each iteration that is sent to the screen.  I am collecting frames of data but I want the frames to appear continuous even though they are not.  This will slow down the update rate but that is alright.

Comment: I am going to experiment with sending smaller chunks at a time.

Comment: Thanks I will check out the smoothing down of progress bars.

Comment: I am going to lock the send rate to the client to a frequency based on the rate of the data request.  I originally thought the producer was going to be much faster than it was so that is why I made it into a producer/consumer thread.  This is more like a frame rate problem where I need to synchronize the output at a consistent rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have a thread that updates the screen once a sec?  The thread can sleep for a sec, wake up, check into what the producer and the consumer are doing, and update the screen based on their progress.  You would get updates every second.  If you want them faster or slower, then change the timer interval.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to lock the send rate to the client to a frequency based on the rate of the data request. I originally thought the producer was going to be much faster than it was so that is why I made it into a producer/consumer thread. This is more like a frame rate problem where I need to synchronize the output at a consistent rate.